# MainActivity is Crashing With Status Bar Notification

Tags: android

I reasearched this, and this code is what I got

The app crashes when I open the MainActivity

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
   new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
   .setContentTitle("Get Other APW Co. Apps on Play!")
   .setContentText("Want more? All our apps are free!");
   int mNotificationId = 001;
   NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemmService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, builder.build());
```

Comment: Post the logcat crash report. And a little more context in the current code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `contentIntent`, i.e. the `PendingIntent` that will be executed when the item is clicked. **It's mandatory,** and you haven't specified it which causes the error.

You can do this in the builder or on the `Notification`:

- in builder:

  ```
  builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
  Notification n = builder.build();
  ```
- on Notification:

  ```
  Notification n = builder.build();
  n.contentIntent = contentIntent;
  ```

Only after can you send it to the `NotificationManager`:

```
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, n);
```

The exact `contentIntent` value depends on what you want to do. See reference here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentIntent

See working example here: https://github.com/nheid/unitedcoders-android/blob/master/src/com/unitedcoders/android/examples/download/DownloadProgress.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Give context name `getSystemmService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`.
       notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    String notificationTitle = "App Name";
    String notificationText = Msg;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog),
            context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,
            0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle,
            notificationText, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
    notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
     "Notification!",
     System.currentTimeMillis());
   Context context = getApplicationContext();
   String notificationTitle = "Get Other APW Co. Apps on Play!";
   String notificationText = ""Want more? All our apps are free!"";
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(SOME_URL));
   PendingIntent pendingIntent
     = PendingIntent.getActivity(AndroidNotification.this,
       0, myIntent,
       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
   myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
      notificationTitle,
      notificationText,
      pendingIntent);
   notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);

  }});
```